# Problema ArrayList - C#

Tags: c#

Tengo el problema de querer extraer un elemento de un ArrayList como tal, por que cuando tengo que usar dicho elemento para alguna operacion me dice que es de tipo object aca va el ejemplo

```
    ArrayList Lista = new ArrayList() { 1, 3, 4, "100" };
    Console.WriteLine(Lista[1]+2);
```

En este caso el output seria `5` , pero como explique antiormente el problema es que me dice que es de tipo object y que la operacion no puede llevarse a cabo.

Comment: Por que usas `ArrayList`? Por que tienes una lista con objetos de diferente tipo?

Comment: Si exactamente.

Comment: No era una afirmación,sino una pregunta. Por que quieres almacenar datos de diferente tipo en una lista?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estás obligado a usar ArrayList porque los elementos pueden ser de cualquier tipo, tendrás que castear/convertir los elementos antes de usarlos.
Por ejemplo:

```
ArrayList Lista = new ArrayList() { 1, 3, 4, "100" };
foreach(var l in Lista) {
    if (l is int)
        Console.WriteLine(((int) l) + 2);
    if (l is string)
        Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(l) + 2);
    // etc para los distintos tipos de datos
}
```

Comment: Si, es lo que estaba pensando... muchas gracias es lo mas cercano a lo que tenia en mente, pero mas que nada quize preguntar por si habia algun fragmento de sintaxis q no conociera para que objeto salga en su forma de origen o algo por el estilo.

Comment: si lo quieres hacer un poco mas elegante puedes hacer  un switch por le type de dato

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList almacen los datos como tipo object por lo que necesitas hacer un cast al tipo de dato correspondiente para realizar la operacion en este caso int:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(Lista[1]) + 2);
```

o alternativamente

```
Console.WriteLine((int)(Lista[1]) + 2);
```

Comment: Claro el tema es que con un ArrayList los datos pueden ser varios no hay alguna forma de sacar el tipo de dato de forma "generica " por asi decirlo

Answer (score 0):

Los ArrayList almacenan datos tipo Object si quieres evitar caster usa generics
ejemplo

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
```

de esta manera evitas el casteo y si llegas a ratar de meter un tipo de dato diferente te saldra el error en tiempo de compilacion, ademas al ser un valor con un tipo de dato declarado lo que estas guardando en la lista generica es mucho mas rapida que guardar un tipo object

Comment: Claro el tema es que necesito tener varios tipos de datos diferentes en un arreglo y despues poder sacar sin problema